# Xcode Thread Status Instrument: it doesn't show my threads

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, instruments

I create a simple sample project from `Single View iOS project` and add only these code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSThread *neverEndingThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runForever) object:nil];
    neverEndingThread.name = @"neverEndingThread";
    [neverEndingThread start];
}

- (void)runForever
{
    while (YES) {
        NSLog(@"thread is running");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

When running, I can see the log printed repeatedly.

Then I use profile run and choose Thread States Instrument:
[image]

To my surprise, in the track pane, it shows no thread at all, not only my thread, but even the main thread is not shown, what have I done wrong?

This is what it look like:
[image]

Comment: In your Instruments snapshot, you haven't started recording yet (and Instruments no longer automatically starts recording). Or are you saying that even after you actually started recording, you still don't see any activity there?

Comment: @Rob dude, I've recorded, I stopped the recording since during recording, I saw no statics, the recorded time has a different color from non-recorded time.

Comment: @Rob also I can prove that since this is the fifth run already

Comment: Just asking', because when I did it, the threads showed up fine. Looking more carefully at image, I see that there was a session recorded. My bad. I was trying to figure out why your thread activity wasn't not showing up for you. I just tried again, this time with Dispatch tool, too, and it didn't show up. But repeated again with just Thread States tool, and it showed up fine.

Comment: @Rob Yes, you are right, using Thread States only will show the right result, maybe this is a bug of Instruments